# already defined in persontype error

Tags: c++

I keep an error basically saying all membershiptype functions are already declared created in the persontype class i was wondering how do i fix this error the first error message says that membershiptime::membershiptype is also defined in the person type object which it is not,and also the second error message says that the second construcor is also already defined in persontype how do i fix this error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class addressType {  //class defintions and prototypes member variables
public:
    addressType();
    string streetAddressNum, streetName, streetType, city, stateInitials;
    int zipCode;
};
class personType
{
public:
    personType();
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int personNum;
    char gender;
    int personID;
    addressType address;
    void setInterest1(string interest1);//mutator
    void setInterest2(string interest2);
    void printPerson();
    string  GetInterest1() const;    // Accessor
    string  GetInterest2() const;
private:
    string SetInterest1;
    string SetInterest2;
};

//define membershipType class
class membershipType :public personType
{
public:
    char membership_type;
    char membership_status;
    membershipType();  // 1st constructor
    membershipType(char, char);  // 2nd constructor
    void print_member_type();
};
 membershipType::membershipType() 
{
     membership_type = ' ';
     membership_status = ' ';
}
 membershipType::membershipType(char members1, char members2)
 {
     members1 = membership_type;
     members2 = membership_status;;
 }
void membershipType::print_member_type()
{
    cout << firstName << " " << lastName << " " << gender << " " <<
        personID << " " << address.streetAddressNum << " "
        << address.streetName << " " << address.streetType
        << " " << address.city << " " << address.stateInitials
        << " " << address.zipCode << " " <<membership_status<<membership_type<<endl;
}


#include "personType.h"
personType::personType()
{//constructor
    int personNum = 0;
    int personID = 0;
}
addressType::addressType() {
    int zipCode = 0;
}
void personType::setInterest1(string interest1) {
    SetInterest1 = interest1;
}//mutator
void personType::setInterest2(string interest2) {
    SetInterest2 = interest2;
}
string personType::  GetInterest1() const
{
    return SetInterest1;
}// Accessor
string personType:: GetInterest2() const {
    return SetInterest2;
}

void personType :: printPerson() {//constructor

    cout << firstName << " " << lastName << " " << gender << " " <<
        personID << " " << address.streetAddressNum << " "
        << address.streetName << " " << address.streetType
        << " " << address.city << " " << address.stateInitials
        << " " << address.zipCode << " " << SetInterest1 << " " << SetInterest2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you have this backwards: `members1 = membership_type;` The value on the right is assigned into the variable on the left.

Comment: In `personType::personType()`, `int personNum = 0;` creates a new local (Automatic) variable that [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the `personNum` member variable. The local variable is set to 0. The member variable is left uninitialized.

Comment: Please rewrite your question, and replace that hard to follow stream of consciousness with a clearly defined and stated question, specifically: instead of paragraphrasing or interpreting whatever compilation errors occur, show the exact compilation errors, verbatim. Figure out how to copy-paste them, and indicate which lines those compilation errors are referencing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to organize you class separately :

```
//main.cpp 

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
#include "membershipType.h"


membershipType::membershipType()
{
    membership_type = ' ';
    membership_status = ' ';
}
membershipType::membershipType(char members1, char members2)
{
    members1 = membership_type;
    members2 = membership_status;;
}
void membershipType::print_member_type()
{
    cout << firstName << " " << lastName << " " << gender << " " <<
    personID << " " << address.streetAddressNum << " "
    << address.streetName << " " << address.streetType
    << " " << address.city << " " << address.stateInitials
    << " " << address.zipCode << " " << membership_status << membership_type << endl;
}


personType::personType()
{//constructor
    int personNum = 0;
    int personID = 0;
}
addressType::addressType() {
    int zipCode = 0;
}
void personType::setInterest1(string interest1) {
    SetInterest1 = interest1;
}//mutator
void personType::setInterest2(string interest2) {
    SetInterest2 = interest2;
}
string personType::GetInterest1() const
{
    return SetInterest1;
}// Accessor
string personType::GetInterest2() const {
    return SetInterest2;
}

void personType::printPerson() {//constructor

    cout << firstName << " " << lastName << " " << gender << " " <<
    personID << " " << address.streetAddressNum << " "
    << address.streetName << " " << address.streetType
    << " " << address.city << " " << address.stateInitials
    << " " << address.zipCode << " " << SetInterest1 << " " << SetInterest2 << endl;
}

int main() {
    personType* p = new personType;
    p->printPerson();
}
```

The personType.h :

```
#include "addressType.h"
class personType
{
public:
    personType();
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    int personNum;
    char gender;
    int personID;
    addressType address;
    void setInterest1(std::string interest1);//mutator
    void setInterest2(std::string interest2);
    void printPerson();
    std::string  GetInterest1() const;    // Accessor
    std::string  GetInterest2() const;
private:
    std::string SetInterest1;
    std::string SetInterest2;
};
```

You addressType.h

```
class addressType {  //class defintions and prototypes member variables
public:
    addressType();
    std::string streetAddressNum, streetName, streetType, city, stateInitials;
    int zipCode;
};
```

Your membershipType.h

```
//define membershipType class
class membershipType :public personType
{
public:
    char membership_type;
    char membership_status;
    membershipType();  // 1st constructor
    membershipType(char, char);  // 2nd constructor
    void print_member_type();
};
```

1>------ Début de la génération : Projet : ConsoleApplication2, Configuration : Release Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>  Génération de code en cours
1>  All 52 functions were compiled because no usable IPDB/IOBJ from previous compilation was found.
1>  Fin de la génération du code
1>  ConsoleApplication2.vcxproj -> C:\out\frosbite_sdk_typeinfo\SDK\ConsoleApplication2\Release\ConsoleApplication2.exe
========== Génération : 1 a réussi, 0 a échoué, 0 mis à jour, 0 a été ignoré ==========

Comment: On re-read, this is a useful answer, it just needs a bit more explanation up front of what the Asker got wrong, why it is wrong, and how your proposed code solves the problem. Otherwise it is essentially a code-only answer, and all people seem to get from code-only answers is practice cutting and pasting.

Comment: @user4581301 nothing wrong just it was a patchwork :) lol. Sorry i didn't read when i open i was alone and out and i posted without looking after my come back ...